# How can I force a file to be created using Cons, if nobody depends on it?

Tags: cons

The project I'm using uses `Cons` instead of `Make` for one section, for reasons beyond my control (i.e. we inherited and there was never enough ROI to switch to Make).

I just added a new rule to create a file that I need in an unrelated part of the project.  By "unrelated" I mean that it's outside the scope of my `Cons` script.  The project build assumes that the part that uses `Cons` is 100% done before the part that needs the new file.

Because of this, there is no target in `Cons` that requires the new file, so `Cons` doesn't build it.  How can I tell `Cons` to build it regardless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the `Depends` method:

```
$CONS->Depends("target", "file_i_want_to_create");
```

This makes `target` dependent on `file_i_want_to_create`.  If `target` is something that will definitely be built (such as the actual project that we want to build with `CONS` ) then `file_i_want_to_create` will definitely be created.